# Making $\mathbb R^n$ a vector space over $\mathbb R$ of dimension $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it possible to endow $V_{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R^n$ with $+$ and $\cdot$ operations in such a way that with those operations, the vector space $(V_{\mathbb R}, + , \cdot)$ over $\mathbb R$ is having dimension $1$?

If yes what are examples of those operations?

Comment: Yes, pick any bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Can you make {⁂,♥,₡,№,⍌} a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is possible. Choose a bijection $b: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and define $\lambda \cdot v = b^{-1}(\lambda b(v))$ and $v+w=b^{-1}(b(v)+b(w))$.